# freebase autosuggest tags

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, autosuggest, freebase, tag-it

I'd like to be able to use the same Freebase autosuggest plugin but with the added ability to add multiple entries to a single field separated by commas.

I know that they are using some variation on jquery-ui autocomplete but can't figure out how to do this using their modified JS. http://www.freebase.com/docs/suggest

Any ideas?

Or use something like Jquery [Tag-it](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/)

Comment: Your link moved: [freebase suggest](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-widget).